# Stripe checkout test returns 404

Tags: stripe-payments

I am testing Stripe Checkout in local with:

```
stripe listen --forward-to 127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook
```

It was working few days ago but without changing the actual code I am now getting 404 errors.

This are the logs:

```
--> payment_intent.created [evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN0Al4ibqW]
2021-08-12 15:04:40  <--  [404] POST

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN0Al4ibqW]
2021-08-12 15:05:02   --> customer.created 

[evt_1JNdakFyXFlaq0dNqFlAbkIF]
2021-08-12 15:05:02  <--  [404] POST 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_1JNdakFyXFlaq0dNqFlAbkIF]
2021-08-12 15:05:03   --> payment_intent.succeeded 

[evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN0e9Q7lgU]
2021-08-12 15:05:03  <--  [404] POST 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN0e9Q7lgU]
2021-08-12 15:05:03   --> charge.succeeded 

[evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN03ssOfWj]
2021-08-12 15:05:03  <--  [404] POST 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_3JNdaOFyXFlaq0dN03ssOfWj]
2021-08-12 15:05:03   --> customer.updated 

[evt_1JNdalFyXFlaq0dNupGNsAGX]
2021-08-12 15:05:03  <--  [404] POST 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_1JNdalFyXFlaq0dNupGNsAGX]
2021-08-12 15:05:06   --> checkout.session.completed 

[evt_1JNdalFyXFlaq0dNEkUu9GX9]
2021-08-12 15:05:06  <--  [404] POST 

http://127.0.0.1:5000/custom_webhook [evt_1JNdalFyXFlaq0dNEkUu9GX9]
```

What is the most common cause of this error?

Thank you!

Comment: you'd look at the logs of the application server you wrote(the server you have running at port 5000 on your machine that implements that custom_webhook endpoint) since that's the application returning a 404.

Comment: Added the logs to the question

Comment: Those are the logs from stripe-cli — it sends the event to your local server running at port 5000. All it knows is your local server returned a 404. You have to look into that server(the code you wrote for handling the webhook). It could be as simple as your server crashed for example.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what was wrong. I updated the git repo (with a last push) and now it works. I did not change the webhook code... However, why would my server crash? I'm working in local!